# __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType) in Admin Panel Django

Tags: django, django-admin

I am using Django and I am getting an error in the admin panel "TypeError at /admin/notifications/notification/5/change/
**str** returned non-string (type NoneType)"
Why do I encounter this error?

**Model**

```
class Notification(models.Model):
TYPES = ((1, 'Reports'), (2, 'User Accounts'), (3, 'Inbox'), (4, 'Attributes Builder'))
incident_report = models.ForeignKey('incidentreport.IncidentGeneral', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
incident_remarks = models.ForeignKey('incidentreport.IncidentRemark', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
sender = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name="noti_from_user")
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="noti_user")
responder = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name="noti_responder")
notification_type = models.IntegerField(choices=TYPES)
remarks = models.CharField(max_length=90, blank=True)
text_preview = models.CharField(max_length=90, blank=True)
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
is_seen = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

[image]

Comment: You did not include the full code of your model.

Comment: I think you return nullable column on __str__() method of model class. Post your model __str__() method code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have encountered this problem because of your model's `__str__()` method. (hard to say cause you haven't included the whole code)

**Why use `__str__()`**:

If you want Django to show a specific field when returning an instance of your model, you can use the model's `__str__()` method. (Check out the explanation in [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjTtPzUt-n7AhWXbKQEHapRAkEQFnoECDUQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.geeksforgeeks.org%2Fchange-object-display-name-using-__str__-function-django-models-python%2F&usg=AOvVaw3dM6zW5Om3K5bO_h8jJFdm))

**Avoid the Error**:

While overriding the `__str__()` method, you should consider that your desired field might be **None** sometimes. In order to avoid this kind of problem you might want to consider this approach:

*Models.py:*

```
class Notification(models.Model):
.
.
.
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name if self.name else str(self.id)
```

- Remember that `__str__()` should return a string; so don't forget to cast the field value if it's not a string.